# Jquery nth-child shows undefined for index 1

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The html code is as follows:

```
<div id="customer-projects">
      <h3 class="lead"> Projects </h3>
      <ul class="project-list">
        .
        .
      </ul>
      .
      .
      <ul class="project-list">
        .
        .
      </ul> 
<div>
```

Is there any particular reason why `$('#customer-projects .project-list:nth-child(1)').html()` returns 'undefined' and not the contents of the first ul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your selector like this, cuz the issue is, you are using `nth-child(1)` which will match `h3` element and not the `ul.project-list`, so it will `return undefined`, use `nth-of-type(1)` with `element.class` selector.

```
console.log($('#customer-projects ul.project-list:nth-of-type(1)').html());
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/dGMp4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq)  like

```
$('#customer-projects .project-list:eq(0)').html(); //indexing starts from 0
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/myEmS/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `:eq(1)` instead of `:nth-child(1)`